# How do I get ata-style IDs in /dev/disk/by-id to work for USB disks?

Tags: linux, udev, usb-drive, disk

I have USB drive dock that I'm plugging SATA drives into. The way they show up in `/dev/disk/by-id` seems to be dependent on whether the drive has a partition table (`usb` if not, `ata` if yes). This makes use with ZFS a bit awkward.

Initial state with fresh drive:

```
% ls -alF /dev/disk/by-id | grep sdd              
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Nov 18 20:47 usb-WDC_WD30_EFRX-68EUZN0_000000000012-0:0 -> ../../sdd
```

Creating partition table gets `/dev/disk/by-id` sorted out but gets ZFS confused because the drive vanishes at the path it had been using:

```
% sudo zpool create -f -o ashift=12 offsite_3TB -m /mnt/offsite_3TB /dev/disk/by-id/usb-WDC_WD30_EFRX-68EUZN0_000000000012-0:0
cannot resolve path '/dev/disk/by-id/usb-WDC_WD30_EFRX-68EUZN0_000000000012-0:0-part1': 2
```

With this initial dance complete, things work as expected:

```
% ls -alF /dev/disk/by-id | grep sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Nov 18 21:22 ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4NPUZ4ZFR -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 18 21:22 ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4NPUZ4ZFR-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 18 21:22 ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4NPUZ4ZFR-part9 -> ../../sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Nov 18 21:22 wwn-0x50014ee260198109 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 18 21:22 wwn-0x50014ee260198109-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 18 21:22 wwn-0x50014ee260198109-part9 -> ../../sdd9
% sudo zpool create -f -o ashift=12 offsite_3TB -m /mnt/offsite_3TB /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4NPUZ4ZFR
```

(completes successfully)

Nothing was [un]plugged during this sequence.

When initially plugged in, `kern.log`:

```
kernel: [1540491.548519]  sdd: unknown partition table
```

After zpool create:

```
kernel: [1542568.022312]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
kernel: [1542625.260285]  sdd: sdd1 sdd9
```

Why does `/dev/disk/by-id` change? These `ata` style paths are what I want, since I don't want the path to change based on whether the drive is directly on the SATA bus or in the USB dock. **Is there a more elegant way to get the `ata` style IDs to show up without intentionally failing a zpool creation?**

FWIW, Ubuntu 14.04 with ZFS-on-Linux PPA.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this problem out? I have a similar problem with Ubuntu 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/q/577564/62622

Comment: I did not. Though to clarify, it only manifests on empty disks. Once they've got the partition table they show up right away with the expected /dev/disk-by-id/ata-* paths when subsequently plugged back in.